# msi installation on a specific drive using powershell

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to install msi file using power shell with arguments, can someone please tell me how to specify the specific location to install on that. i am trying various ways but its not letting me to do that.
Thanks

Comment: zabbix_agent-4.4.4.msi is in C drive and i want this to install it in D:\Monitoring\zabbix\

Comment: Have you read their doco? https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/installation/install_from_packages/win_msi

Comment: It would help if your question included the powershell command that you have tried.

Comment: SET INSTALLFOLDER=C:\Program Files\za

msiexec /l*v log.txt /i zabbix_agent-4.0.6-x86.msi /qn^
 LOGTYPE=file^
 LOGFILE="%INSTALLFOLDER%\za.log"^
 ENABLEREMOTECOMMANDS=1^
 SERVER=192.168.6.76^
 LISTENPORT=12345^
 SERVERACTIVE=192.168.10.1^
 HOSTNAME=myHost^
 ENABLEPATH=1^
 INSTALLFOLDER="%INSTALLFOLDER%"
 SKIP=fw
The above command worked on command line, could you please tell me how to do this on powershell. i want to execute this on a remote server using powershell.